# How to open a link via "router.push" in a new tab using Nextjs router from next/navigation

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, router, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am developing a Nextjs app and would want to direct user to another link using `router.push` but I do not know how to open the link in new tab.

My code is like this right now:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const router = useRouter();

 <Button
          onClick={() => {
            router.push(`${mylink}`);
          }}
        >
          Order
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `router.push` does is a redirection to the route you defined. Here what you want is to open a new tab on a different link.
You can use NextJS Link and set the target as `_blank`

```js
import Link from "next/link";

<Link href={mylink} target="_blank">Order</Link>
```

If you want a button you can do it like this

```js
<Link href={mylink} target="_blank">
 <Button>Order</Button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Ok but I am using a button instead of a Link otherwise I know Link would work. If you can find me a solution for Button other than what I found that would be great.

Comment: You can wrap your link around a button then

Comment: Because you'd usually don't want to use side effect like `window.open` it's a bad practice you better use cleaner ways like target=_blank

Comment: I tried and it worked perfectly. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the issue I had to use the code below and get it working for external links.

Best for internal links:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const router = useRouter();

<Button
  onClick={() => {
    router.push(`${mylink}`);
     }}>
      Order
</Button>
```

But for external links it is better to use window.open() like the code below.

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    window.open({mylink});
     }}>
      Order
</Button>
```